# Why can't i change from Row Level Tracking to Column Level Tracking?

Tags: sql-server, replication

I'm implementing Merge replication on SQL Server 2019. Everything is working fine and I decided to look into conflicts.

All my table articles are set to Row Level Tracking and I want to switch to Column Level Tracking for them. I can change the setting to Column Level in the Publisher options for all the table articles with no problem. Unfortunately, when I reopen the properties, all the changes have reverted to Row Level.

I've tried recreating the Publisher in a script, setting @column_tracking = 'false', but that doesn't work either.

Is there another setting somewhere that I've missed that allows the value to be change?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that the articles *were* set to column level tracking, but there is a feature in the properties window that means that when you reload it and go for all table values it displays them as Row level. If you look at them individually, they are column level. I'd call that a bug...